# apply method on Map object?

Tags: scala, dictionary

First of all let me apologize in advance for what is my very first question posted on stack overflow and probably a quite stupid one.

Since a Map in scala is instantiated using the following syntax:

```
val myMap=Map(1->”value1”,2->”value2”)
```

I was expecting the Map object from `scala.collection.immutable` to provide an `apply` method with a signature roughly looking like:

```
def apply[A,B](entries :(A,B)*):Map[A,B]
```

Obviously I should be blind, but I can’t find such a method. Where is it defined ?

Furthermore, could someone give me information about the purpose of the `Map1`, `Map2`, `Map3`, `Map4` classes defined in the `Map` object ? Should they be used by the developer or are they only used internally by the language and/or the compiler ? Are they related somehow to the map instantiation scheme i was asking about above ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.1/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map$ - here is your apply method.

Comment: You can read more about scala collections and `MapN` classes from Programming in scala [Default sets and maps](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/collections.html#tab:default-maps)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`apply` looks like it is defined on `scala.collection.generic.GenMapFactory`, a superclass of `scala.collection.immutable.Map`. For some reason, Scaladoc simply ignores this method for 2.9.2. (As Rogach notes, it was there in [2.9.1](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.1/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map$).)

`Map1`…`Map4` (together with `EmptyMap`, which is private) are simply optimisations. These are defined inside [Map.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala) and really just hold up to four keys and values directly without any further indirection. If one tries to add to a `Map4`, a `HashMap` will automatically be created.

You normally do not need to create a `Map[1-4]` manually:

```
scala> Map('a -> 1)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,Int] = Map('a -> 1)

scala> res0.isInstanceOf[scala.collection.immutable.Map.Map1[_,_]]
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: I didn't thought scaladoc could have 'forgotten' a method. Next time i will double-check in the documentation and in the source code.
Thank you.

Comment: It looks like a bug in scaladoc. [MapFactory](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.generic.MapFactory) shows `empty` and `newBuilder` methods from `GenMapFactory`, but not `apply`.

Comment: The documentation is produced correctly on [nightly](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map$).